# Add message to Google Group

Tags: google-admin-sdk, service-accounts, google-workspace

I am attempting to add a message to a G-suite group using the g[roup migration API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/v1/get-start/getting-started).  The POST command looks like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/groups/v1/groups/groupname@domain.com/archive?uploadType=media&access_token=ya29.Gm03...
```

Assume that "groupname@domain.com" is valid - I'm substituting the correct value here.  The access token value is shortened above, but it should be valid.  This was obtained using OAuth and the administrator id for my G-Suite domain.  I can use this token successfully for the email API.

I have enabled the "group migration API" in my service account, and in my G-suite account, have enabled the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.migration" for that service account.  This scope is requested when I get the authentication token.

The problem?  http error 401 (Unauthorized).  Prior to getting to this point, I had received other http errors, such as 403 (forbidden) due to errors in scope, or 404 (not found) when I had the wrong group id.  so I think I have gotten past that.  What other steps do I need to take for proper authorization?

Comment: Are you sure this is the API you should be using?   https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-migration/v1/guides/manage-email-migrations

Comment: The documentation you pointed to is in fact the API that I am using - same POST url.  The only difference I see is that instead of putting the auth token in the url, they put it in the http headers.  I tried it the way documented but still get the same error.  I do see some information to the effect that emails added will only go to the archive, not distributed to the group.  I wanted to make sure that archiving was enabled for my group, but there appears to be no way to do that.

Comment: There appear to be different types of "groups" that Google defines - those with domain googlegroups.com and those created in G-Suite.  I can't set archiving for G-Suite groups - what gives?

Comment: Based on the service-accounts tag you're using, I assume you're using a service account to get the OAuth token. If that's the case - did you use delegation to get an OAuth token as a superadmin of the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure archiving is enabled for the group. In a browser, logged in as a super admin, go to

```
https://groups.google.com/a/DOMAIN_NAME.com/forum/?#!forum/GROUP_NAME
```

and then go `Manage > Information > Content control > Archive options` and ensure `Archive messages to the group` is ticked ON and click Save.